# Outlook Issue - Cannot delete an email from Deleted Items folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm using an Outlook of desk application on Windows 10 Pro Platform.

I'm facing the problem about the cannot delete email items from deleted Items folder.

The **Litigation hold** was enabled in the user account.

I want to know what way can I troubleshoot by myself?

Comment: I think a hold like that can only come from Exchange so you should talk to your Company.

Comment: Do you mean the Litigation Hold mentioned in this article( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/policy-and-compliance/holds/litigation-holds?view=exchserver-2019)? If so, agree with John, the issue may be related to Exchange, It is suggested that you could contact the administrator of your organization to check the relevant settings of litigation Hold.

Comment: I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you have any questions or need further help on this, feel free to post back.

Comment: I was contacted the administrator, also I'm working with him, and helping to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you need any help about outlook client, feel free to post back.